# Getting a segmentation fault when trying to build my GCC backend

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-construction, cross-compiling, porting

I am currently trying to write a GCC backend for a new architecture, but when I try to compile it I get the following error message:

```
xgcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault signal terminated program cc1
```

The build is configured with the following command:

```
../gcc/configure --prefix=--prefix=$HOME/GCC-10.0.1 --disable-bootstrap --target=arch_name --enable-languages=c
```

How would I go about fixing this error so that I can build my backend?

As far as I am aware, I have implemented the target macro's, functions and insn patterns required to get GCC to build.

Sorry that the question is a bit vague, I am not sure what extra information I can provide. If more specific information is needed please let me know and I will edit the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I go about fixing this error so that I can build my backend?

Debug `cc1`.

1. `xgcc` is located in `$builddir/gcc`.  Hence run `$builddir/xgcc -B$builddir -v -save-temps <options-that-crash-cc1>`.
2. `xgcc -v ...` will print the sub-commands it is calling, record the options it supplies to the crashing `cc1` call.
3. Run a debugger against that `cc1` call, supply the right options and put a breakpoint at `abort` (will be `fancy_abort`) actually.
4. Build the compiler without optimization.  It's enough to run `make` in `$builddir/gcc` for that. You can supply additional option if you like, e.g. `make -j4 cc1 CXXFLAGS='<flags-to-pass>'`.
5. `$builddir/gcc` provides `.gdbinit` to augment `gdb` with additional hooks to improve debugging experience.